# Use default and custom liquibase configurations in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, liquibase

I'd like to use two configurations of Liquibase in current project. The default configuration I'd like to use for DDL changes and second one for custom inserts where changelog will be in another location.

If I configure `SpringLiquibase` the default autoconfiguration will be skipped due to `@ConditionalOnClass(SpringLiquibase.class)` annotation in `LiquibaseAutoConfiguration` class. 
How can I use default autoconfiguration + my custom? Can I overwrite the @ConditionalOnClass annotation somehow? Or maybe is there way how to tell Liquibase that I have another changelog outside of application and run it only if it's present?

Thanks

**edit:**

This could be the solution for my problem, however I have problem with loading external files (files outside of classpath) in liquibase.

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(LiquibaseProperties.class)
public class LiquibaseConfiguration {

    @Bean
    SpringLiquibase liquibase(DataSource dataSource, LiquibaseProperties properties) {
        SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
        liquibase.setChangeLog(properties.getChangeLog());
        liquibase.setContexts(properties.getContexts());
        liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
        liquibase.setDefaultSchema(properties.getDefaultSchema());
        liquibase.setDropFirst(properties.isDropFirst());
        liquibase.setShouldRun(properties.isEnabled());
        liquibase.setLabels(properties.getLabels());
        liquibase.setChangeLogParameters(properties.getParameters());
        liquibase.setRollbackFile(properties.getRollbackFile());
        return liquibase;
    }

    @Bean
    SpringLiquibase commandInitializerLiquibase(DataSource dataSource,
            @Value("${docu.system.initializer.command.liquibase.changeLog}") String changeLogPath,
            @Value("${docu.system.initializer.command.liquibase.contexts}") String contexts) {
        File changeLog = new File(changeLogPath);
        SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
        liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
        liquibase.setContexts(contexts);
        liquibase.setIgnoreClasspathPrefix(true);
        liquibase.setChangeLog(changeLog.getAbsolutePath());
        liquibase.setShouldRun(changeLog.exists());
        //liquibase.setResourceLoader(liquibaseResourceLoader());
        addPathToClassloader(changeLogPath);
        return liquibase;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

If you want to use Spring Boot autoconfigured Liquibase feature then you can have only one `SpringLiquibase` bean in your context. 
This is because of `@ConditionalOnMissingBean(SpringLiquibase.class)` annotation in `LiquibaseAutoConfiguration` class. Spring's conditional feature searches for `SpringLiquibase` instances and it's subclasses instances, so extending `SpringLiquibase` class won't fix that problem.

There is no good way to override `LiquibaseAutoConfiguration`.
In that case you have 3 solutions which could solve your problem:

**1) Implement two separate Liquibase bean configurations:**

```
@Configuration
public class LiquibaseConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    //define this property in your embedded properties file or use spring's default
    @Value("${liquibase.change-log}")
    private String defaultLiquibaseChangelog;

    @Bean
    public SpringLiquibase liquibase() {
        SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
        liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
        liquibase.setChangeLog(defaultLiquibaseChangelog);
        // Configure rest of liquibase here...
        // ...
        return liquibase;
    }
}
```

and

```
@Configuration
public class LiquibaseConfiguration2 {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    //optional, define it in external configuration or through command line param
    @Value("${liquibase.change-log-additional:#{null}}")
    private String additionalLiquibaseChangelog;

    @Bean(name = "additionalLiquibase")
    public SpringLiquibase liquibase() {
        if (additionalLiquibaseChangelog != null) {
            SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
            liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
            liquibase.setChangeLog(additionalLiquibaseChangelog);
            // Configure rest of liquibase here...
            // ...
            return liquibase;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**2) Use `Liquibase` instead of `SpringLiquibase` for manually configured liquibase instance**

Use one autoconfigured `SpringLiquibase` and one pure `Liquibase` configuration instead of `SpringLiquibase` (You will need to manually run your migrations and handle other stuff which is implemented in `SpringLiquibase`)

**3) Use only one SpringLiquibase instance**

Use combination of Liquibase's `changelogParameters` (http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changelog_parameters.html), `include` tag (http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/include.html) and  only one `SpringLiquibase` instance.

**Example implementation:**

**Liquibase bean configuration**

```
@Configuration
public class LiquibaseConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    //define this property in your embedded properties file or use spring's default
    @Value("${liquibase.change-log}")
    private String defaultLiquibaseChangelog;

    //define this property in your embedded properties file
    @Value("${liquibase.extended-change-log}")
    private String extendedLiquibaseChangelog;

    //optional, define it in external configuration or through command line param
    @Value("${liquibase.data-change-log:#{null}}")
    private String liquibaseDataChangelog;

    @Bean
    public SpringLiquibase liquibase() {
        SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
        liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
        if (liquibaseDataChangelog != null) {
            //here you can check if file exists...
            Map<String, String> liquibaseChangelogParameters = new HashMap<>();
            liquibaseChangelogParameters.put("liquibaseExternalDataChangelogPath", liquibaseDataChangelog);
            liquibase.setChangeLog(extendedLiquibaseChangelog);
            liquibase.setChangeLogParameters(liquibaseChangelogParameters);
        } else {
            liquibase.setChangeLog(defaultLiquibaseChangelog);
        }
        // Configure rest of liquibase here...
        // ...
        return liquibase;
    }
}
```

**changelog.xml (liquibase.change-log)**

```
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.3.xsd">

    <include relativeToChangelogFile="true" file="changelog-master.xml"/>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

**changelog-with-external-data.xml ( liquibase.extended-change-log )**

```
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.3.xsd">

    <include relativeToChangelogFile="true" file="changelog-master.xml"/>
    <include relativeToChangelogFile="false" file="${liquibaseDataChangelogPath}"/>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

Remember that having separate changelogs could be dangerous. You have to make sure that your changelogs are independent:

> Included change-logs are run in the order they are found so care does
>   need to be taken to make sure that the included changelogs are either
>   completely independent, or that any required changelogs are run first.

Comment: Include tag does not work for me, because there could be situation where entire changelog does not exists. If there were a flag failOnMissingFile it could help me. One changelog as I said is inside application within which will be shipped only DDLs and that other changelog I want to use for data import and will be outside of application.

Comment: Yeah, right, it ain't gonna work in that case. If your situation depends on environment then you can consider using spring profiles for loading different logback configuration files (one with only DDL included and other with included both: DDL and external data )

Comment: Check my extended answer, hope it helps